# In Endgame, why were these characters still around?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* the final battle features both

> Chitauri and Outriders

However, I was under the impression all the

> Chitauri were killed in 2012, so 2014 Thanos shouldn't have them.

So, did they come back or were they still around post-*Avengers*? If they were, where were they in *Avengers: Infinity War* at Wakanda?

Comment: Well, only the ones in New York were killed. Maybe he had more garrisoned somewhere else.

Comment: At least one Chitauri (general) survived the assault on New York. Probably there were others; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xBmTPE4Z_8

Comment: Was it ever stated every sing Chitauri alive was in NYC?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Chitauri weren't completely wiped out in *Avengers* as we see one member of the Chitauri still alive in The Collector's collection in *Guardians of the Galaxy*.

[image: Chitauri still alive in The Collector's collection in _Guardians of the Galaxy_]

As such we can assume that the nuke blast in *Avengers* only killed those being controlled by the mothership that it blew up and not the entire army.

We also know of The Other, the Chitauri leader, who survived up until some point in *Guardians of the Galaxy* when Ronan kills him. This backs up the theory that again not all of the Chitauri were killed.

[image: The Other]
<sub>*Click to enlarge.*</sub>

A deleted scene from *Avengers: Infinity War* also shows a member of the Chitauri working on Nebula and guarding her before she escapes. This is non-canon (as it was changed for the film) but shows that the film's creators might have believed them to have survived.

[image: Chitauri working on Nebula]

Comment: Although I agree that because we saw the Chitauri in "The Avengers" die, doesn't necessarily mean that *all* Chitauri died then, in my opinion none of the facts you present serve as an answer. The Chitauri in the Collector's collection was held in a showcase and was probably dead, the sole fact that their leader surviving until GOTG doesn't prove that the Chitauri as a race survived as well, while the scene in IW was deleted and as you yourself said, cannot serve as a canon evidence. Even its CGI was incomplete; who knows what they did want to show.

Comment: @Lefteris008 The Chitauri in the collection moves, watch the scene back https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkYpZJsrbJI

Comment: What was that scene changed to? I thought it was a Chitauri in the final cut.

Comment: @AzorAhai some armoured dude... https://youtu.be/65arS8hFmAs

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Huh, I just figured it was a Chitauri this whole time.